# Copy text/data from drop down menu when user click button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("1");
  var copyText = document.getElementById("2");
  copyText.select();

  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<select id="1">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Carrot</option>
</select>
<select id="2">
  <option>Fruit</option>
  <option>Vegetable</option>
</select>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

When Apple and Fruit is selected in the drop down, and click Copy text button, my clipboard will have "Apple/Fruit"

I can't figure it out. Please help.

Comment: sorry I'm not use to posting in stackoverflow. I'll do it next time

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I updated my post. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with what's wrong:

1. you are reusing the same variable `copyText` for both elements, hens only the last element will be available in that variable.
2. as the error shows, element `select` (which is delcared into `copyText` variable) doesn't have function `select()`
3. you are trying copy to clipboard a value from a single element

So, to minimally fix your code you'll need declare two different variables for your elements, and combine values from both into one:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText1 = document.getElementById("1");
  var copyText2 = document.getElementById("2");

  var value = copyText1.value + "/" + copyText2.value;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(value);

  alert("Copied the text: " + value);
}
```

```html
<select id="1">
     <option>Apple</option>
     <option>Carrot</option>
</select>
<select id="2">
     <option>Fruit</option>
     <option>Vegetable</option>
</select>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```